# Converting a Angular 1.X method to Angular 2.5 $interval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm converting a angular 1.X website to angular 2.5 and I'm having an isuue converting the angular 1.x JS code to angular 2.5 below:

```
checkJobStatusInterval = $interval(function () {
    cartService.checkDownloadStatus1().then(function (keepChecking) {
        //if there is no more job running, stop checking
        if (!keepChecking) {
            _stopChecking();
        }
        _updateCartStatus();
    })
}, config.downloadCheckingInterval);
```

more specifically how do I convert the $interval and function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$interval` is Angularjs specific, and there is no similar in Angular 2+, everyone uses the usual [**`setInterval`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), regular JavaScript method. You can simply do:

```
checkJobStatusInterval = setInterval(function() {
  // Other stuff inside
}, config.downloadCheckingInterval);
```